# How to convert UTM to Longitude/Latitude in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, utm

Hi Stack Overflow community!

I have a dataframe that includes 2 columns of UTM coordinates ('X' and 'Y') as shown on the screenshot below:

[image: utm coordinates]

I have been trying to convert and replace those 2 columns into Longitude and Latitude as shown below:

```
    Longitude   Latitude
    1.601554    42.546245
    53.847818   23.424076
    67.709953   33.93911

    ... and so on
```

Here's the code I usded:

```
    def rule(row):
        lat, lon = utm.to_latlon(row["X"], row["Y"])
        return pd.Series({"lat": lat, "long": long})
    df.merge(df.apply(rule, axis=1), left_index= True, right_index= True)
```

FYI, to import **utm**, I have installed the [utm 0.4.2](https://pypi.org/project/utm/) using Terminal.

However, it keeps giving me the following Type Error when i ran the code:

[image: type error]

I am really new to data science and Python, so it is very difficult for me to figure out what I have done wrong.. :'(

Any helps or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for utm](https://pypi.org/project/utm/#Description), you'll note that `to_latlon` takes four required arguments. You've only given it two (latitude and longitude), so you're missing `Zone Number` (as seen in the error) plus `Zone Letter`.

Comment: Hi @JoshFriedlander! Thank you so much for your comment! I entered the `Zone Number`, however, now it gives me the Name Error. Here's the [screenshot of the code I entered, and the error message.](https://i.imgur.com/A5pez0T.jpg) If you can offer me additional guidance, that'd be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: No problem. You have a typo here: `long` instead of `lon`

Comment: It works! Thank you a million @JoshFriedlander! Really appreciate your help on this!